# How to make SVG <use> element rotate around its own center?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I used an SVG as part of another SVG. I want to control to rotate the `<use>` element in the SVG around the center of the `<use>` element itself. I followed the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56491257/how-to-rotate-a-svg-object-around-its-own-center) to set `transform-origin` and `transform-box` in the CSS. However, it does not work.

Here are my codes. You can drag the slider to rotate the  element (carrot) I want to rotate. How can I make the carrot rotate around its own center?

```js
const slider = document.getElementById("slider")
const myUse = document.getElementById("myUse")
slider.oninput = function(){
  myUse.style.transform = "rotate("+slider.value+"deg)"
}
```

```css
#myUse{
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-box: fill-box;
}
```

```html
<svg id="carrot" fill="#000000" viewBox="0 0 50 50" width="50px" height="50px">
  <path d="M30 13c-1-3-5-4-7-2h-1l1-11h-3l-1 9-4-7-3 1 5 8-8-4-1 2 9 5h-1c-2 2-3 5-2 7l2 2 5-3 1 2-5 3 8 9 5-3 2 2-5 3 12 14 3-2-8-25-5 3-1-2 5-3-3-8"></path>
</svg>


<svg>
  <use id="myUse" x="30" y="30" href="#carrot" style="transform: rotate(0deg);"></use>
</svg>

Rotation
<input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="360" value="0" step='1' >
```

Expected result: [image: Expected result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `x` and `y`, or use [translate3d](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate3d) if you want to position it to not overflow:

```js
const slider = document.getElementById("slider")
const myUse = document.getElementById("myUse")
slider.oninput = function () {
  myUse.style.setProperty('--r', `${this.value}deg`);
}
```

```css
#myUse {
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-box: fill-box;
    transform: translate3d(25px, 25px, 0) rotate(var(--r, 0deg));
}
svg {
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<svg id="carrot" fill="#000000" viewBox="0 0 50 50" width="50px" height="50px">
  <path d="M30 13c-1-3-5-4-7-2h-1l1-11h-3l-1 9-4-7-3 1 5 8-8-4-1 2 9 5h-1c-2 2-3 5-2 7l2 2 5-3 1 2-5 3 8 9 5-3 2 2-5 3 12 14 3-2-8-25-5 3-1-2 5-3-3-8"></path>
</svg>


<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100px" height="100px">
  <use id="myUse" href="#carrot"></use>
</svg>

Rotation
<input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="360" value="0" step='1' >
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it really solves my problem. May I ask why `x` or `y` will make it does not work?

Comment: It doesn't work with `x` and `y` because the [transform-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box) is related to CSS [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform), also there were no sizes defined for bounding box, i.e. parent `svg`. It may work with `x` and `y` also, but `translate` is the preferred way to work with animated objects.