# how to rotate svg element about its center in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I am trying to do something similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74034206/how-to-make-svg-use-element-rotate-around-its-own-center) but can't get it to work in react js. I tried several different methods, but didn't really get any progress. If i use `transform rotate (deg, cx, cy)` it moves all over the place and is hidden. When I tried the `transform3d` as in the post, it doesn't move at all. please help, thanks.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

// import SVGStyles from "./SVGStyles";

function SVGComponent() {
  const svgRef = useRef(null);
  const [rotate, setRotate] = useState(45);
  const [viewBox, setviewBox] = useState("0 0 24 24");

  function handleChange(event) {
    setRotate(event.target.value);
  }

  function rotateSvg() {
    if (svgRef.current) {
      const bbox = svgRef.current.getBBox();
      const cx = bbox.x + bbox.width / 2;
      const cy = bbox.y + bbox.height / 2;
      // setviewBox([bbox.x, bbox.y, bbox.width, bbox.height].join(" "));

      svgRef.current.style.setProperty("--r", `${rotate}deg`);
      // svgRef.current.setAttribute(
      //   "transform",
      //   `rotate(${rotate}), ${cx}, ${cy}`
      // );
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <svg ref={svgRef}>
        <Triangle viewBox={viewBox} style={{ border: "1px solid red" }} />
      </svg>
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <label>
        Angle:
        <input
          type="range"
          min="0"
          max="360"
          value={rotate}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        {rotate}°
      </label>
      <button onClick={rotateSvg}>Rotate</button>
    </>
  );
}

const Triangle = (props) => (
  <svg
    height="100%"
    viewBox={props.viewBox}
    fill="none"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    style={props.style}
  >
    <path
      fillRule="evenodd"
      clipRule="evenodd"
      d="m13.789 1.578 9.764 19.528A2 2 0 0 1 21.763 24H2.237a2 2 0 0 1-1.789-2.894l9.764-19.528a2 2 0 0 1 3.578 0Z"
      fill="#758CA3"
    />
  </svg>
);


export default SVGComponent;
```

The css is verbatim from the post:

```
svg {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  transform: translate3d(25px, 25px, 0) rotate(var(--r, 0deg));
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

Comment: 3D transformations are currently not supported for svg elements. I'd recommend using the svg transform attribute - the code you've commented out has a typo: you've closed `rotate()`before specifying the pivot point. It should actually work. See [codepen](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/YzjEqdp). You might also need to shift your pivot point slightly below the center x/y to match the visual/weighted  centroid of your triangle.

Comment: awesome! thanks so much for that rapid solution. I fiddled with your code and got it to work in my setup. Thanks again!